# Not all images show up when reading directly from an SD card out of Nikon D5100?

Tags: nikon-d5100, apple-aperture

I shot about 35 images on my new Nikon D5100. Turned off the camera, ejected card, inserted it into the SD slot on my Dell 3014 monitor. About 3/4 of the images turned up in the Aperture import window. Put the card back into the camera, cabled the camera into place, and everything was there.

This bugs me because I want to share this camera with my daughter, and I thought the simplest trick was to hand her her own SD card and a reader for her laptop, so she wouldn't have to plug the camera into her computer.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you copied the images directly off the card to your hard drive and used Finder to see if they're all there and show a preview? It's possible that your card has a fault in it causing this.

Comment: No ... when they were all there as seen through the camera cable I stopped and posted this question. It's a brand-new card, btw. I'll try more experiments.

Comment: New card doesn't mean no fault in it. However, it could also be the card reader itself. Either way, having a look from Finder rather than Aperture is probably a good idea.

Comment: This happened to me one: perhaps some of the images were in JPG and some in RAW, and your import only selected either of these...?

Answer (score 1):

Use Windows Explorer or Finder to browse the SD card contents. Things to look for:

1. Is there more than one folder containing images? If so, perhaps your importer is browsing only one (default) folder. Some cameras will use file numbers up to a certain number, then cycle through the file numbers again, but in a new folder.
2. Per Jack's comment - are some images in different format to others (eg. JPEG versus RAW/NEF, etc)? If so, your importer may be selecting only certain file types.